# How to bypass "The file has been changed since reading it"?

Tags: save

When I try to save a file I get the attached error almost every time. I haven't opened or modified the file in different editor.

This is for Elixir files, and the code get compiled. Not sure if that is the cause of this error.

Is there anyway that I can bypass this as it is getting super annoying. 
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Has the file's modification date been updated?

Comment: No, I use `:w` to save the file. I get that error. I don't even compile or anything. I just go to another editor, then I come back to it and change a character and type `:w` and I get the same error again!!

Comment: But *something* seems to modify the file, I think? You can use e.g. `ls -l` (or a graphical file manager) to check the file's modification time.

Comment: Ok, I ran the `ls -l` on the file, then I used `:w` and I got the error. so I saved the file anyway. Then I ran the `ls -l` which it was updated as I expected. Then I ran `ls -l` again and again to make sure that nothing is changed which was the case. Then when I tried to run the `:w` I got the same error.

Comment: Now if I leave the file for about 5 min alone and not save it, when I go back to it and type `:w` it saves it fine with no issue.

Comment: `:h W11` it also talks about how to prevent this error.

Answer (score 2):

By any chance are you using Acronis True Image? I found that the new "Active Protection" they provide was causing exactly this problem. Going into Settings -> Manage Processes and adding the full path to gvim.exe as a trusted application got rid of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As correctly stated by Christian Brabandt [in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14698/how-to-bypass-the-file-has-been-changed-since-reading-it#comment25235_14698), use `:h W11` to see possible reasons for such warning.

In my own case I was editing file located on the Samba share under Windows and possible inconsistency in timezones across Win/*nix invoked such warning.
Putting the file to Linux machine solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this warning when editing a file on a cifs share. My local machine time was ahead of the remote system (by ~30min) due to incorrect date&time/timezone setting. Once sorted,the vim warning stopped !

vim 8.0
Local and remote systems: Linux

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while editing a Redis configuration.
This error occurred when I was editing a file while a process or service was using that file.

By stopping or killing the respective process, I was then able to edit and save the file without error.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I've edited for some clarity—if I've accidentally misunderstood what you mean, you should be able to rollback the edit (or let me know). You can also [edit] yourself.